# How to stop polling in HTMX? 286 does not stop htmx from continuing to poll

Tags: htmx

According to the HTMX docs, polling should stop after it receives a response code of 286.

Given this code:

```
    <form
        id="board"
        hx-post="/xxx/start"
        hx-select="#board"
        hx-trigger="every 1ms"
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
    >
```

My server is responding with a 286 code:
[image: server response]

why does it continue to ping my server?

Comment: It might have something to do with your interval being set to 1ms. The requests are probably being queued and continue responding. You should avoid using such low interval for pulling, change it to larger value (eg 1s should be minimal depending on your network), or just use SSE.

Comment: @mariodev tried this at 1s but I get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on an [old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/wkovxo/best_way_to_use_htmx_polling_to_update_a_div/)

> As a side note, i ran into an issue using hx-swap: outerHTML where the 286 status code did not stop the polling since the hx element is part of refresh. I’m thinking I can nest another div inside and select that element to fix that tho.

In retrospect this makes a lot of sense.

The solution:

```
<form
    id="board"
    hx-post="/xxx/start"
    hx-trigger="every 500ms"
    hx-select="#board-content"
    hx-target="#board-content"
    hx-swap="outerHTML"
>
    <div id="board-content">
       // rest of form 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Lol just today I was having the same problem, and its just been answered 2 days ago. thanks for sharing :)